# Nodemon not refreshing browser in React-Express-Node App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, nodemon

I have installed `nodemon` **locally** in my workspace, but even though it restarts in the terminal after changes are made, it does not refresh the browser page. I have to manually refresh it each time.

I've got Express, Node, React and Webpack running in the environment.

This is how my setup looks like -

[image]

My `package.json` starts up `server.js` -

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

and `server.js` is -

```
var express = require('express');


     var app = express();
        app.use(express.static('public'));
        app.listen(3000, function () {
            console.log("Express server is up on port 3000");
        });
```

The `entry point` in the webpack config file is -

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './public/scripts/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/scripts/bundle.js'
    }
```

What should I do to fix it?

---

Update -

I made a [video](https://youtu.be/-EdIWmQs1hs) to describe the situation, if it helps.

Comment: For those needing to use nodemon and reload browser on change as well, I replied here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089425/7779953 Solution is Nodemon + Browser Sync + Gulp + Express server

Answer (score 23):

nodemon is only for restarting the server when your server code changes. It has no functionality to reload your page in the browser. If you want automatic browser reload, you could, for example, run a webpack dev server in addition to your nodemon. webpack dev server is able reload the page in the browser when your client code changes, it can even update the page in the browser without a full page reload, if you use its hot module reloading feature.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: i have server side rendering in my app. as soon as my react code changes, the browser will refresh the page, but the problem is with the serve side rendered html. it still remains the same, until i terminated the server

Comment: I run webpack in watch mode for both the server and the client to prevent this

Answer (score 7):

in package.json

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "nodemon server.js -e html,js,css"
},
```

in server js

```
var reload = require('reload')

app.listen(3000, () => {

  console.log(`Listening on port 3000`);
})

reload(app);
```

in index.html

```
<body>
  <h1>ron</h1>
  <script src="/reload/reload.js"></script> <!-- it's necessary -->
</body>
```

Comment: Here's the link to the reload package on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reload

Comment: This `express` example with `reload` is more intuitive than the [docs on github](https://github.com/alallier/reload).