# Changes are not reflecting in the browser

Tags: reactjs, npm, adminlte

I downloaded this reactJS project https://github.com/booleanhunter/ReactJS-AdminLTE. Making any changes is not reflecting in the browser.I am running below commands:

`npm run build` it shows:

```
> adminlte-reactjs@1.0.6 build /home/manish/do_practice/admin-lte
> webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js

Hash: 3e7c0fb0bc633a60f191
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 3716ms
                   Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    ./reactjsAdminlte.js    86.5 kB       0  [emitted]  reactjsAdminlte
./reactjsAdminlte.js.map  139 bytes       0  [emitted]  reactjsAdminlte
    + 37 hidden modules

WARNING in ./reactjsAdminlte.js from UglifyJs
Condition always true [./~/velocity-animate/velocity.js:429,2]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/velocity-animate/velocity.js:433,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable a [./src/components/chat-box/chat-box.js:54,20]
Dropping unused variable button [./src/components/custom-box/box-tool.js:24,11]
Dropping unused variable that [./src/components/info-tile/progress-bar.js:15,20]
```

Then i execute: `npm run dev` it shows:

```
> adminlte-reactjs@1.0.6 dev /home/manish/do_practice/admin-lte
> node server.js

Server listening at port 8000
```

Comment: Changes are not reflected after you run `npm run dev`?

Comment: yes correct not even text r haning

Comment: I don't think it has live reload implemented. It is just a plain node-express server underneath

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: Why do you need live reload on this project? Are you planning on contributing?

Comment: no i just want to see my changes on browse whenever i reload

Comment: i cant even see simple text change

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622125/how-can-i-add-live-reload-to-my-nodejs-server