# Nodemon not reloading page

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am starting studying Node.js, so I am using nodemon to reload my page, but it's not working and already tried all Stack solutions aswell.

Look how simple is my code:

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
  }
}
```

> server.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hey');
});

app.listen(3001);
```

My bash while interacting with `res.send()` message.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using nodemon with the server. It is restarting the server as you make changes to the server.js file. That is, your endpoints are being updated. This will not cause your client to reload. As you are simply navigating to the endpoint that you are creating within the browser, you will not see the changes reflected without refreshing.

That isn't to say that there is no benefit to running nodemon in this way. If you were not doing so you would need to also close the node instance (ctrl-c) and then rerun it every time before refreshing the page. Otherwise, you would still be running the old version of your server and still see the same content served.

Eventually you will consume these endpoints using an http client from your client application, this is generally when you take advantage of a hot reloading environment. There are some options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089425/5007662) if you want to make express live-reload before then.

Comment: The `server.js` code is being displayed in my browser instead of running and showing only the message. Also, could you explain in another way why isnt reloading and why npx is an alternative?

Comment: He is saying that nodemon is doing it's job, but if you want your browser to reload when your server does, you will need a tool other than nodemon. Browser-sync is a good option, too.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer, I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much guys!