# How to run live server after Node.js and npm installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-live-server

I am using Windows 10 and I have installed Node.js (with npm) on my local machine. I am trying to follow an instruction which says:

```
"Once node.js and npm are installed, run the following command in your terminal.

npm install -g live-server

This will install live-server⁵, a simple static server that has live reload built-in. To
start your server, run live-server in your terminal from the root /code folder —
it will even open a new browser window for you!"
```

Since I am on Windows, I guess "Terminal" means "Command Prompt". So, I have run the "`npm install -g live-server`" from C:// prompt.

I am now confused about the part where it says "run `live-server` in your terminal from the root /code folder".

What is the `root /code folder`?

Comment: Well where are the files you want to serve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the command prompt, either cmd.com or Windows terminal (yes, the [new one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) actually has [the word "terminal"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) in its name), `cd` to your project directory (referred to by the docs as the "root" or "code" folder) then type:

```
live-server
```

It is literally installed as a command just like `cd`, `dir` etc.

The "root" folder or "code" folder is literally the folder where you saved your `index.html` file.

Comment: highly recommend the new Windows Terminal app, as it allows unix commands

Comment: The word literally is completely unnecessary in your answer.

Comment: @Willa It does make a difference. Sometimes there can be things that behave like commands but not commands in shells such as aliases. However, live-server is installed as an actual command. That means it is **literally** installed as a command, not just command-like

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to your root folder of your project and run

```
npm install live-server
```

2. To start live server run:

```
npx live-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Root folder is where your index.html is saved.(from which your code runs). You can use `cd` `../` to change your folder and get to root.  After which you can easily run live server.

Answer (score 0):

Default - `npm install live server -g`

MacOS - `sudo npm install live server -g`

Here, npm stands for node package manager and helps us to install various packages.We are requesting npm to install the live server package!

The `-g` tag implies we are installing it globally (meaning it is available everywhere on our computer).

After installation, run `live-server`.