# How to set up nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I've installed nodemon like this:

```
npm install nodemon -g
```

And I run it like this `nodemon myapp` assuming myapp is the folder where the app is. However, after I make changes to let's say style.css I do not have this automatic page reload. What can be the way to solve that?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3NOc.jpg

Comment: `nodemon` does not reload a web page when files are changed. It is a server-side reloading of node.

Comment: your new stylesheet are already applied as soon as you saved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodemon not refreshing browser in React-Express-Node App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43152968/nodemon-not-refreshing-browser-in-react-express-node-app)